# ef6 query many to many using bridge

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

how do I query this many to many relationship?  I am starting with ACCOUNT, and want to return the ExecutingBroker.Firm associated with it.

I am starting with Account, then I guess drill to MANAGER, then to MAPPING_MANAGER, then to EXECUTINGBROKER.

Here is my query so far...

```
            var student = dbEF.Accounts        
                        .Where(x => x.AccountNumber == acctNum)
                        .Select(x => new DTOCrmDetails()
                        {
                            AccountNumber = x.AccountNumber,
                            AccountName = x.AccountName,
                            DateOpened = x.DateOpened,

                            CommissionId = x.CommissionId,
                            Commission = x.Commission,

                            ManagerID = x.ManagerID,
                            ManagerName = x.Manager.ManagerName,
                            Manager = x.Manager,

                            Employees = x.Manager.Employees,

                            WireInstructionsUSD = x.Manager.WireInstructionsUSDs

                        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

[image]

below is the code that was generated from ef from existing database.

```
    public partial class Manager
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Manager()
    {
        this.Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        this.WireInstructionsUSDs = new HashSet<WireInstructionsUSD>();
        this.Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers = new HashSet<Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers>();
    }

    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string Strategy { get; set; }
    public string ManagerShortCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WireInstructionsUsdID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WireInstructionsForeignID { get; set; }
    public string MEtradingPlatform { get; set; }
    public string EtradingCostResp { get; set; }
    public string NotesManager { get; set; }
    public bool MainStrategy { get; set; }
    public string PathPayments { get; set; }
    public string PathEtrading { get; set; }
    public string LEI { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WireInstructionsUSD> WireInstructionsUSDs { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers> Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers
{
    public int Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokersId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ManagerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ExecutingBrokersId { get; set; }

    public virtual ExecutingBroker ExecutingBroker { get; set; }
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
    public partial class ExecutingBroker
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ExecutingBroker()
    {
        this.Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers = new HashSet<Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers>();
    }

    public int ExecutingBrokersId { get; set; }
    public string Firm { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers> Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up navigation properties on the relevant entities? I see in Account you have one for Manager. The Manager needs one for the Mapping, the Mapping needs one for the ExecutingBrokerFirm. Then you could call Account.Manager.Mapping.ExecutingBrokerFirm.

Comment: I added the code of the entities... from what I understand the navigation properties are already there

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through `Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers`, since you've modelled it that way.
Keep in mind that you have a collection of Firms, since it's a many-to-many-relationship.

```
.Select(account => new { Firms = account.Manager.Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers
                                .Select(meb => meb.ExecutingBroker.Firm) });
```

Comment: sorry don't understand.  Firms is just a string.  and the code that you wrote, how would I incorporate that in my original query?

Comment: I added tag [JsonIgnore] to MANAGER and it seems to work.  not sure why though.  does that seem right?

Comment: @solarissf No, Firms is just not a string. You described (and the model confirms this) as a many-to-many-relationship. I.e. each Manager can have (belong to?) several ExecutingBrokers, and an ExecutingBroker can have several Managers.

Your DTO `DTOCrmDetails` need to have a collection of strings (I named that property `Firms` in my example). If you only want to have one string `Firm` in your DTO, you have to join them: `string.Join(', ', account.Manager.Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers.Select(meb => meb.ExecutingBroker.Firm)`.